# For loop that won't save values of counter

Tags: python

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of each string in my nested list
(it it much larger on my computer, below is a sample to demonstrate the structure)

```
lst = [[545300, ['sub10', 'sub13']], [546636, ['sub15', 'sub17']], [546648, ['sub15', 'sub17']], [8775, ['sub14', 'sub17']], [65, ['sub11', 'sub14']]]

sh1 = 0
sh2 = 0
sh3 = 0
sh4 = 0
sh5 = 0
sh6 = 0
sh7 = 0
sh8 = 0

for pos, sampleList in lst: 
    if 'sub10' in sampleList: 
        sh1 += 1
    elif 'sub11' in sampleList: 
        sh2 += 1
    elif 'sub12' in sampleList: 
        sh3 += 1
    elif 'sub13' in sampleList: 
        sh4 += 1
    elif 'sub14' in sampleList: 
        sh5 += 1
    elif 'sub15' in sampleList: 
        sh6 += 1
    elif 'sub16' in sampleList: 
        sh7 += 1
    elif 'sub17' in sampleList: 
        sh8 += 1
```

End goal:

| sub10 | sub11 | sub12 | sub13 | sub14 | sub15 | sub16 | sub17 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 2 |

The issue is that the value for 'sub17' always comes up as 0, even though I can see many instances of 'sub17' in the list when I print it. All other counters are working fine, it's just the last "elif" that won't work.

I've also tried:

```
for pos, sampleList in lst: 
    if 'sub10' in sampleList: 
        sh1 += 1
    elif 'sub11' in sampleList: 
        sh2 += 1
    elif 'sub12' in sampleList: 
        sh3 += 1
    elif 'sub13' in sampleList: 
        sh4 += 1
    elif 'sub14' in sampleList: 
        sh5 += 1
    elif 'sub15' in sampleList: 
        sh6 += 1
    elif 'sub16' in sampleList: 
        sh7 += 1
    else: 
        sh8 += 1
```

I feel like the answer is probably something obvious and I just need a fresh (or more advanced) set of eyes to look over it.

Comment: Why don’t you print and examine `sampleList` as the first statement in the `for` loop so you can see what’s going on. Don’t rely on assumptions, instead find out what values are in your variables, which I ams sure will help you understand why your code isn’t doing what you expect/want.

Comment: FYI you’d be better using lists rather than repeating all those if tests.

Comment: Do you need the variables `sh1`, etc... or would a dictionary mapping the names such as "sub10" to counts do?

Answer (score 3):

Using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

res = Counter(sum(dict(lst).values(), []))
print(dict(res))
```

---

```
{'sub17': 3, 'sub15': 2, 'sub14': 2, 'sub10': 1, 'sub13': 1, 'sub11': 1}
```

Without `collections.Counter`:

```
vals = sum(dict(lst).values(), [])
res = dict.fromkeys(vals, 0) 
for val in vals:
    res[val] += 1
print(res)
```

---

```
{'sub17': 3, 'sub15': 2, 'sub14': 2, 'sub10': 1, 'sub13': 1, 'sub11': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary, where keys are the string you're counting, and values are the count.

```
counts = {}
for pos, sampleList in lst: 
    for item in sampleList:
        # .get() returns the value at counts[item], and 0 if none exists
        # Then you increment this and save it to counts[item]
        counts[item] = counts.get(item, 0) + 1
```

This way, you don't have to hardcode all the `if` statements, and you don't have a mess of variables to deal with.

With your example `lst`, the value of `counts` is:

```
{'sub10': 1, 'sub13': 1, 'sub15': 2, 'sub17': 3, 'sub14': 2, 'sub11': 1}
```

To access the count of a given string, you can use `.get()` again:

```
print(counts.get("sub17", 0)) # Gives 3
print(counts.get("sub12", 0)) # Gives 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter` to count the values. Instead of a complicated set of getters and iterators, just use a simple for loop.

```
import collections

lst = [[545300, ['sub10', 'sub13']], [546636, ['sub15', 'sub17']], [546648, ['sub15', 'sub17']], [8775, ['sub14', 'sub17']], [65, ['sub11', 'sub14']]]

counts = collections.Counter()
for _, vals in lst:
    counts.update(vals)
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use elif:

```
lst = [[545300, ['sub10', 'sub13']], [546636, ['sub15', 'sub17']], [546648, ['sub15', 'sub17']], [8775, ['sub14', 'sub17']], [65, ['sub11', 'sub14']]]

sh1 = 0 
sh2 = 0 
sh3 = 0 
sh4 = 0 
sh5 = 0 
sh6 = 0 
sh7 = 0 
sh8 = 0

for pos, sampleList in lst: 
    if 'sub10' in sampleList: 
        sh1 += 1
    if 'sub11' in sampleList: 
        sh2 += 1
    if 'sub12' in sampleList: 
        sh3 += 1
    if 'sub13' in sampleList: 
        sh4 += 1
    if 'sub14' in sampleList: 
        sh5 += 1
    if 'sub15' in sampleList: 
        sh6 += 1
    if 'sub16' in sampleList: 
        sh7 += 1
    if 'sub17' in sampleList: 
        sh8 += 1
```

By using elif, you just check for the smallest value that appears (since you ordered them that way), and sub17 is always in the second position in your example.

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you so much I think this solved it !